# Blur android view

Tags: android, view, effects

I need a method that allows the blur effect to apply to any android View (such as ImageView, TextureView, Button, etc.). I have the necessary shader, but I do not know how to apply it to the View. Or maybe there needs another way?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by necessary shader? You have a partial transparent image/color to create the blureffect with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273171/blur-effect-like-in-the-app-etsy

Comment: There is a class implements OpenGL shader

Comment: I'd say go with @RajeshCp answer. I did it the same way in one of my apps

Comment: Thank you for link. But it seems to me that this method will not be applicable for textureView (eg in the case of video playback). In any case, thanks for the link, I'm thoroughly familiar with what is written there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use a drawable overlay. This coulb be a png images with some blury effect that you will apply on any view, for example by applying a custom style.

Comment: Actually, the better way is to use a custom shader. You canno't really blur without it (or, I do not know how to do it). A shader is a piece of code running on a graphic card. What you do is access all the current renderer pixels and blur the image using gaussian bluring for instance.