# Blur effect Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new in android development. I want to make blur background layout. I read some blog but I didn't get that I want.

I want to make layout like this: http://postimg.org/image/azjkgbl3l/

Suggest me some blogs or how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273171/blur-effect-like-in-the-app-etsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do this,For `API < 14`, you could use the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND`, but it's been deprecated and built-in blurring is no longer supported on higher APIs.So you can create a  blurred bitmap and set it as background for the page. Refer the following links for more details.

[Blur effect like in the app Etsy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273171/blur-effect-like-in-the-app-etsy)

http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/

[Android, how to blur/glass/frost current activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406060/android-how-to-blur-glass-frost-current-activity)